# How to Hide "Out of Stock Products from WooCommerce Search Results" in Wordpress?

Tags: woocommerce

How to Hide "Out of Stock Products from WooCommerce Search Results" in Wordpress ? I Have Tried Many Methods but None works. Please Help me.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully this can help, even though the question is old. Add this in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'misha_hide_out_of_stock_in_search' );

function misha_hide_out_of_stock_in_search( $query ) {

    if( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
        $query->set( 'meta_value', 'instock' );
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean with "search results"? Only for that section?
There is an option in Woocommerce,

```
Woocommerce->Settings->Products->Inventory
```

then check the option that says "`Hide out of stock items from the catalog`".

Its that what you were looking for?

Comment: NO Its Not Working Properly. The Search Page Still Shows those out of stock products.

Comment: Can you describe a more detailed explanaition? What plug-ins do you have installed? Have you tried changing to a Storefront theme? An image of how the store looks?